# Is there any way I can sort a this table using 'ORDER BY'?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, vb.net, database-design

I have an 'accounts' table that contains a group account (isgroup) with subaccount (groupcode):

```
| code | title          | groupcode | isgroup | groupindex |
|------|----------------|-----------|---------|------------|
| 100  | Current Assets |           | 1       | 0          |
| 101  | Cash           | 100       | 1       | 1          |
| 102  | AR             | 100       | 1       | 1          |
| 103  | Property       |           | 1       | 0          |
| 104  | Balance        |           | 1       | 0          |
| 105  | Cash on hand   | 101       | 1       | 2          |
| 106  | Cash in bank   | 101       | 1       | 2          |
| 107  | My Bank 1      | 106       | 0       | 3          |
| 108  | Cahier 1       | 105       | 0       | 3          |
| 109  | Building 1     | 103       | 0       | 1          |
```

Notes:

1. There is no standard way to generate 'code'. It can be any (text)
2. Any account can have as many sub accounts determined by 'isgroup' and 'groupcode'.
3. 'isgroup' determines if the account can have a sub account.
4. 'groupindex' determines the sub account level. Index n(0) is the top level, its sub account will be in index n + 1

I need to sort it like this:

```
| code  | title             | groupcode     | isgroup   | groupindex    |
|------ |----------------   |-----------    |---------  |------------   |
| 100   | Current Assets    |               | 1         | 0             |
| 101   | Cash              | 100           | 1         | 1             |
| 105   | Cash on hand      | 101           | 1         | 2             |
| 108   | Cashier 1         | 105           | 0         | 3             |
| 106   | Cash in bank      | 101           | 1         | 2             |
| 107   | My Bank 1         | 106           | 0         | 3             |
| 102   | AR                | 100           | 1         | 1             |
| 103   | Property          |               | 1         | 0             |
| 109   | Building 1        | 103           | 0         | 1             |
| 104   | Balance           |               | 1         | 0             |
```

The top level account and its sub accounts up to n level must be displayed first, then the next top level account.

I've accomplished the task in application level using recursive function and add the rows one by one to a datatable. Is there any way I can sort this table in one query?

Comment: Which method do you use to fetch the data?

Comment: Can you help us with how you determine the sort?

Comment: I fetched the data using tableadapter to fill a dataset then iterate each row to get all its sub accounts and add it one by one to another datatable.

Comment: You should add if you are using MyQSL 8 (as it supports recursion and makes this problem significantly easier).

Comment: What's the size of the column `code`? This is critical to sort appropriately.

Comment: It's easy to do in MySQL 8.x. In MySQL 5.x it's near to impossible using SQL only.

Comment: @djv as stated in the second table. If an account has a subaccount, all its subaccount should be displayed next.

Comment: @TheImpaler the 'isgroup' is necessary in the application level since it determines if an account can have a sub account. 'code' is varchar(20). Oh my, i'm using MySQL 6.x in visual studio

Comment: MySQL 6.x does not exist. Look at the version again, please.

Comment: @TheImpaler Im sorry. MySQL Runtime version v4.0.30319 version 6.9.9.0

Comment: If you are using MySQL 4.x then you cannot do this at the database level. You need at least MySQL 8.0. You'll need to do it at the application level.

Comment: Even if you could do it at the database level, some things are just easier to implement and maintain at the application level.

Comment: `v4.0.30319 version 6.9.9.0` -- neither is a valid MySQL version.  Can you run `SELECT @@version;`

Comment: @RickJames That's the version of MySQL connector on visual studio. I'm using 10.1.9-MariaDB

Comment: @Melvin - Upgrading to 10.2 would provide CTEs, and may make it practical to use them to solve the task.

Comment: @RickJames Wow thanks. This solves lots of my problems.